# Simple c++ web server sending wrong headers

Tags: c, websocket, webserver

I have very simple web server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
"Server: michal\r\n"
"Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n"
"Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\n\r\n"
"<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>"
"<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>"
"<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>"
"</body></html>\r\n";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 8080;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    printf("got connection\n");

    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

This works in browser, the page is rendering correctly but when I am doing ab test I have error:

```
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 2 requests completed
```

ab works fine when I am benchmarking localhost (Apache)

When I tried to download page with php file_get_contents I have following error:

```
PHP Notice:  file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /home/mitch/Dokumenty/projects/cpp/webserver/webserver/bench.php on line 7
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are terminating connection before client has a chance to send all the request headers it wants.

So adding delay before `close`, or actually reading data before empty line is received would help.

Comment: When I added sleep(1) the page is displayed in browser for 1 second and I have an error, connection refused (in browser)

Comment: @MichałK. Try to send `Connection: close` instead of `Connection: Keep-Alive`

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar problem explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269273/250944 (p.2)

Headers is ok, but you should read something from client first and only then write response, here is diff for your code snippet with added code for reading data:

```
@@ -8,6 +8,8 @@
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <err.h>

+#define MAXMSG  16384
+
 char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
 "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
 "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
@@ -24,6 +26,8 @@ int main()
   int one = 1, client_fd;
   struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
   socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);
+  char read_buffer[MAXMSG];
+  int nbytes;

   int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0)
@@ -50,6 +54,13 @@ int main()
       perror("Can't accept");
       continue;
     }
+    nbytes = read (client_fd, read_buffer, MAXMSG);
+
+    if (nbytes < 0) {
+      perror("Can't read");
+      close(client_fd);
+      continue;
+    }

     write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
     close(client_fd);
```